# Django SearchVector on model IntegerField

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

If I have a simple model like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I use `SearchVector` in postgres to allow for searching on both the title and year fields? E.g. so "Some Book 2018" would query over both the title and year fields.

If I try doing this like:

```
q = SearchQuery('Some') & SearchQuery('Book') & SearchQuery('2018')
vector = SearchVector('title') + SearchVector('year')
Book.objects.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=q)
```

Then I hit the error

```
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 1: ...|| to_tsvector(COALESCE("book_book"."year", '') || ' '...
```

Is there anyway I can search the Integer field too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you read in the error log you cannot use integer in a search vector, but you can easily [cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) your integer into a string in your query.

You can execute this code to made your full-text search with your **Book** model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchVector
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import CharField

q = SearchQuery('Some') & SearchQuery('Book') & SearchQuery('2018')

vector = SearchVector('headline') + SearchVector(Cast('rating', CharField()))

Book.objects.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=q)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I don't suppose you know if it's also possible for django choices fields? Like if it my db I just have small integers corresponding to some choices list. Could a similar thing be done do modify the `SearchVector` by mapping the db values to text values?

Comment: Your question is not clear for, but maybe it will be better if you can create a new question with more detail.

Comment: ok made a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874068/django-searchvector-on-choices-field  thanks for any help