# Django SearchVector on choices field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, full-text-search, django-queryset

If I have a simple Django model like:

```
from model_utils import Choices

class Art(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = Choices(
        (1, 'DIGITAL_ART', 'Digital Art'),
        (2, 'MULTIMEDIA', 'Multimedia'),
    )
    title = models.TextField()
    category = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        db_index=True, choices=CATEGORIES, blank=True, null=True
    )
```

How can I use `SearchVector` in postgres to allow for searching on both the title and categories fields? E.g. so "Some Book Digital Art" would query over both the title and categories fields.

The problem is that at the database-level the choices field is stored as an integer, not text.

Is there a way I could just map the integer to the corresponding text value when creating my search vector?

Comment: Are designing your model or you already have tables and data ? Title and category have the same value for your search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first solution I can think is using [Conditional Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) to add the category text into the [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector):

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector


Art.objects.annotate(
    category_text=Case(
        When(category=1, then=Value('Digital Art')),
        When(category=2, then=Value('Multimedia')),
        default=Value(''),
        output_field=CharField()
    ),
    search=SearchVector('title') + SearchVector('category_text')
).filter(
    search='Some Book Digital Art'
).values_list('title', flat=True)
```

The resuklt of this query will be similar to:

```
<QuerySet ['Some Book']>
```

And the SQL generated for PostgreSQL like this:

```
SELECT "arts_art"."title"
FROM "arts_art"
WHERE (
  to_tsvector(COALESCE("arts_art"."title", '')) ||
  to_tsvector(COALESCE(
    CASE
      WHEN ("arts_art"."category" = 1) THEN 'Digital Art'
      WHEN ("arts_art"."category" = 2) THEN 'Multimedia'
      ELSE ''
    END, '')
  )
) @@ (plainto_tsquery('Some Book Digital Art')) = TRUE
```

## Update

You can automatically build your query from your choices list:

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

CATEGORIES = (
    (1, 'Digital Art'),
    (2, 'Multimedia'),
)

Art.objects.annotate(
    category_text=Case(
        *[When(category=c, then=Value(v)) for c, v in CATEGORIES],
        default=Value(''),
        output_field=CharField()
    ),
    search=SearchVector('title') + SearchVector('category_text')
).filter(
    search='Some Book Digital Art'
).values_list('title', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. Great solution ( On the Update I think you accidentally missed the `Value`, i.e. `then=Value(v)`)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy you find my solution useful. Thanks for your suggestion, I've updated the code example.